# Why innerHtml doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Why doesn't `innerHtml` work?

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function chat()
{
    alert ("started!");
    document.getElementById("test").innerHtml="foo";
}
</script>
<body id="body" onload="chat();">
<p id="test">
test..
</p>
</body>
```

"started!" is showing, but the content of `<p>` doesn't get changed to `foo` as intended. Why?

Comment: @Cœur Making edits to a useless post from almost five years which has no effect other than bumping it back onto the home page seems pointless at best and actively harmful at worst.

Comment: @torazaburo some questions on frequent typo aren't useless. Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269605/my-question-turned-out-to-be-a-rather-esoteric-typo-what-should-i-do-what-sho

Comment: Whether or or not the question is useless, editing it certainly is. And the question you quote doesn't qualify as a "simple" typographical error, while this does.

Comment: if the question wasn't taken down, it's not useless nor is editing it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Casing matters, it's `innerHTML` **not** `innerHtml`. Try this:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="foo";
```

Comment: God bless you! I spent half a hour to find the answer

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a Case Sensitive language so you should always check the case of the code you are writing.

Try using "innerHTML" in place of "innerHtml".

Also, it is a good practice to use Single Quotes(') instead of Double Quotes(") in JavaScript.

Comment: Why not to use double quotes?

Comment: @les: check this page for reference - https://bytearcher.com/articles/single-or-double-quotes-strings-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with an API that returns XML then you likely don't have any innerHtml.  Most browsers support outerHtml.  Try this

```
function getHTML(node){
    if(!node || !node.tagName) return '';
    if(node.outerHTML) return node.outerHTML;

    // polyfill:
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.appendChild(node.cloneNode(true));
    return wrapper.innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are using a mac try using

document.getElementById("test").firstChild.nodeValue = "foo";